# Windows: How to automatically mount second partition made during Windows installation?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have installed Windows 10 alongside my Linux root/swap/home partitions. I wanted to have a similar setup on the Windows part of my drive, so when installing Windows, I created two partitions in the empty space: one for the OS and one larger one for the Users folder.

But I didn't see any option to set up the second partition as a Users partition during the setup, and the second partition I made during the installation (seventh in total on the drive) doesn't even show up in This PC as drive D or whatever.

How can I: automatically mount the second partition made during setup on boot for use, and move Users to that partition?

The partition in question does show up in Windows' "Disk Management" utility.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has no equivalent to this Linux option. You could try to force it
by various means, but you're going to end up with too many problems
(so I don't advise it).

The Windows equivalent is the `C:\Users` folder and
you can not move this entire folder.

However, for one specific user
you can move his folders of `Downloads`, `Documents`, `Pictures`,
`Videos`, and `Music` that are found under the user's folder of
`C:\Users\user-name`.
You may also repeat this for other users.

This is done by in Explorer by right-clicking the folder, selecting
Properties and changing in the Location tab the folder's location.

For more information, see the article
[(Four Ways) Move Users Folder to Another Drive Windows 10 or Windows 11](https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/move-users-folder-to-another-drive-windows-10.html).

Comment: Can I not create more such movable folders? I intend to store my steam games off C:, also, I still don't know how to mount my other partition, but I will research around :-)

Comment: For installing software, especially large games, this can be done in any folder that you like.